# Converting Bitmap image object to Device Independent Bitmap in Microsoft Word (2010)

Tags: microsoft-word

I am attempting to convert a Bitmap image object to Device Independent Bitmap in Microsoft Word by doing the following:

**Right-click on image ->  Bitmap image object -> convert -> Picture (Device Independent Bitmap)**

[image]

[image]
But I always seem to be getting the following error:

> The server application or item cannot be found. Make sure the
>   application is properly installed, and that it has not been deleted,
>   moved, renamed or blocked by policy

[image]

I have tried this on several machines with the same result. What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Click to the image and pres Ctrl+shift+F9. The object is sometimes converted.